# Extension method to escape variable for javascript?

Tags: javascript, razor, encoding, escaping

```
public string GetEscapedTitle() { return Title.Replace("'", "\\'").Replace("\"", "\\\""); }
```

I created the above to deal with issues I ran into when doing this in the view:

```
<a onclick="AddToMyList('@Model.Title', ...
```

That seemed to fix the errors I was getting when the Title contained single or double quotes. But this wasn't the only property I had the issue with so I had this brilliant idea to create an extension method like so:

```
    public static string EscapeQuotes(this string s)
    {
        return s.Replace("'", "\'").Replace("\"", "\\\"");
    }
```

Unfortunately, this put me back to square one and I had the same error I got in the beginning when I used it. So what's the difference?

The only thing I can think of is that maybe with the GetEscapedTitle() method razor encodes it after it's escaped but maybe with the extension method it still somehow gets encoded before the extension method is run? That doesn't make sense to me but it's all I can think of right now for why it wouldn't work. :(

Edit: FYI I also just tried adding the .Replace() calls directly in the razor code and that works perfectly fine. But for some strange reason if I do it in the extension method it won't work.

Comment: Extension methods should return `MvcHtmlString` (_Represents an HTML-encoded string that should not be encoded again._)